# Apply function to columns in where clause with Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Is it possible to use custom functions in where clause with Sequelize?
For instance, I wish to achieve something similar to:

```
models
    .BLA
    .findAll({ 
        where: {
            COL1: something,
            myFunction(COL2): {
                $or: [
                    { $lte: 10 },
                    null
                ]
            },

...
```

Comment: Did you found the solution ?

Answer (score -1):

If it is a SQL function, you can do:

```
models
.BLA
.findAll({ 
    where: {
        COL1: something,
        models.BLA.sequelize.fn('function',
        models.BLA.sequelize.col('COL2')): {
            $or: [
                { $lte: 10 },
                null
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Your example is syntactically incorrect / incomplete. Could you complete it please ? I have the same issue, and I cant find the correct syntax to achieve your solution.

Comment: You can clone example app from git: [sequelize/express-example](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example). Then, add in routes/index.js :  `attributes: { include: [[models.User.sequelize.fn('COUNT', models.User.sequelize.col('username')), 'number']] }` below the line: `include: [ models.Task ], ` inside the findAll function. So, you can use SQL functions with Sequelize.